# Postgres query changes and degrades radically

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a hibernate-based query that is not performing well. It is running a query that joins three tables - `asset`, `asset_type`, and `asset_status` - and sorts the results, and running the query on a database with over a million records in both `asset` and `asset_type` is taking no less than three seconds to run. However, I came across a curious situation this morning: the first time I ran `explain analyze`, the query performed well:

```
explain analyze 
select assetstatu0_.id as col_0_0_, 
       assetstatu0_.status_state_updated_date as col_1_0_, 
       assetstatu0_.status as col_2_0_, 
       assetstatu0_.state as col_3_0_, 
       assettyped2_.name as col_4_0_, 
       assetstatu0_.asset_id as col_5_0_, 
       assetdatad1_.emp_address as col_6_0_, 
       assetdatad1_.smid as col_7_0_ 
  from asset_status assetstatu0_, 
       asset assetdatad1_, 
       asset_type assettyped2_ 
 where assetstatu0_.asset_id=assetdatad1_.id 
   and assetdatad1_.asset_type_id=assettyped2_.id 
   and 1=1 
 order by assettyped2_.name asc 
 limit 20;

Limit  (cost=40.70..16483.30 rows=20 width=782) (actual time=0.144..0.265 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=40.70..2695805.68 rows=3279 width=782) (actual time=0.141..0.259 rows=20 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..12762.19 rows=3125 width=750) (actual time=0.090..0.132 rows=20 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using asset_name_index on asset_type assettyped2_  (cost=0.00..36.40 rows=10 width=524) (actual time=0.043..0.043 rows=4 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using asset_type_id_index on asset assetdatad1_  (cost=0.00..1268.67 rows=313 width=242) (actual time=0.019..0.021 rows=5 loops=4)
                    Index Cond: (assetdatad1_.asset_type_id = assettyped2_.id)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on asset_status assetstatu0_  (cost=40.70..854.47 rows=328 width=40) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=20)
              Recheck Cond: (assetstatu0_.asset_id = assetdatad1_.id)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on asset_id_index  (cost=0.00..40.61 rows=328 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=20)
                    Index Cond: (assetstatu0_.asset_id = assetdatad1_.id)
Total runtime: 0.382 ms
(11 rows)
```

Afterwards, I ran the actual query and it ran fine. When I ran the above `explain analyze`, though, I got much different results:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..25.42 rows=20 width=580) (actual time=0.061..3785.145 rows=20 loops=1)
      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1271077.73 rows=1000014 width=580) (actual time=0.060..3785.141 rows=20 loops=1)
            Join Filter: (assetdatad1_.asset_type_id = assettyped2_.id)
            ->  Index Scan using asset_name_index on asset_type assettyped2_  (cost=0.00..36.40 rows=10 width=524) (actual time=0.011..0.017 rows=4 loops=1)
            ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.00..114603.96 rows=1000014 width=72) (actual time=0.039..870.438 rows=750016 loops=4)
                  Merge Cond: (assetstatu0_.asset_id = assetdatad1_.id)
                  ->  Index Scan using asset_id_index on asset_status assetstatu0_  (cost=0.00..42377.57 rows=1000014 width=40) (actual time=0.020..174.375 rows=750016 loops=4)
                  ->  Index Scan using asset_pkey on asset assetdatad1_  (cost=0.00..57234.84 rows=1000032 width=40) (actual time=0.017..223.734 rows=750016 loops=4)
Total runtime: 3785.204 ms
(9 rows)
```

Now, the performance is never as fast as it was the first time this morning, and it was slow yesterday as well, despite there being no change to the data or the schema. Is there some kind of cache that is being filled up (and can be configured to be auto-purged)? Running `vacuum`, `analyze`, and `discard all` do not have any effect, neither does wiping the schema/data and loading it again. I suspect the "fix" is to leave the database alone for a few hours for whatever cache to be dropped, but that's obviously not a feasible solution.

We are running postgresql v8.4, and the shared memory buffer is 128MB. Below are the schema for the three tables:

```
\d asset
                          Table "public.asset"
          Column           |              Type              | Modifiers 
---------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------
 id                        | bigint                         | not null
 asset_type_id             | bigint                         | not null
 created_date              | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null
 created_user              | character varying(255)         | not null
 deployment_date           | timestamp(0) without time zone | 
 deployment_status         | character varying(255)         | 
 emp_address               | character varying(63)          | not null
 gps_coordinates           | character varying(255)         | 
 hardware_version          | character varying(255)         | 
 in_service_date           | timestamp(0) without time zone | 
 location                  | bigint                         | 
 manufacturer              | character varying(255)         | not null
 previous_asset_link       | character varying(255)         | 
 serial_number             | numeric(19,0)                  | not null
 smid                      | character varying(32)          | not null
 software_version          | character varying(25)          | not null
 status                    | bigint                         | 
 state                     | bigint                         | 
 status_state_updated_date | timestamp(0) without time zone | 
 updated_date              | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null
 updated_user              | character varying(255)         | not null
 area_id                   | bigint                         | not null
 version                   | numeric(19,0)                  | 
Indexes:
    "asset_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "asset_smid_key" UNIQUE, btree (smid)
    "asset_type_id_index" btree (asset_type_id)
    "emp_address_index" btree (emp_address)
    "smid_index" btree (smid)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "asset_area_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES area(id)
    "asset_asset_type_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (asset_type_id) REFERENCES asset_type(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "asset_event" CONSTRAINT "asset_event_asset_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (asset_id) REFERENCES asset(id)
    TABLE "asset_status" CONSTRAINT "asset_status_asset_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (asset_id) REFERENCES asset(id)
    TABLE "asset_variables" CONSTRAINT "asset_variables_asset_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (asset_id) REFERENCES asset(id)
    TABLE "custom_asset_fields" CONSTRAINT "custom_asset_fields_asset_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (asset_id) REFERENCES asset(id)

\d asset_type
                 Table "public.asset_type"
    Column    |              Type              | Modifiers 
--------------+--------------------------------+-----------
 id           | bigint                         | not null
 name         | character varying(255)         | not null
 created_date | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null
 created_user | character varying(255)         | not null
 updated_date | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null
 updated_user | character varying(255)         | not null
 scac         | character varying(255)         | not null
 small_icon   | character varying(255)         | not null
 large_icon   | character varying(255)         | not null
 short_name   | character varying(255)         | not null
 description  | character varying(255)         | not null
 type         | character varying(255)         | not null
 type_code    | character varying(255)         | not null
 version      | numeric(19,0)                  | 
Indexes:
    "asset_type_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "asset_type_name_key" UNIQUE, btree (name)
    "asset_type_type_code_key" UNIQUE, btree (type_code)
    "asset_name_index" btree (name, id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "asset" CONSTRAINT "asset_asset_type_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (asset_type_id) REFERENCES asset_type(id)
    TABLE "asset_plugin_version" CONSTRAINT "asset_plugin_version_asset_type_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (asset_type_id) REFERENCES asset_type(id)

\d asset_status
                      Table "public.asset_status"
          Column           |              Type              | Modifiers 
---------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------
 id                        | bigint                         | not null
 created_user              | character varying(255)         | not null
 created_date              | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null
 updated_user              | character varying(255)         | not null
 updated_date              | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null
 version                   | numeric(19,0)                  | 
 asset_location            | character varying(255)         | 
 component_id              | bigint                         | not null
 response_code             | bigint                         | 
 state                     | bigint                         | 
 status                    | bigint                         | 
 status_state_updated_date | timestamp(0) without time zone | 
 asset_id                  | bigint                         | not null
Indexes:
    "asset_status_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "asset_id_index" btree (asset_id)
    "created_date_index" btree (created_date)
    "state_index" btree (state)
    "status_index" btree (status)
    "status_updated_index" btree (status_state_updated_date)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "asset_status_asset_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (asset_id) REFERENCES asset(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "status_variable" CONSTRAINT "status_variable_status_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (status_id) REFERENCES asset_status(id)
```

Comment: It is obvious that the plan changed between the two runs.  This is usually due to changes in the statistics, often seen with values that occur very rarely.  Have a look at a blogpost from a colleague of mine: https://tech.zalando.com/blog/analyzing-extreme-distributions-in-postgresql/ Furthermore, consider moving to a recent PostgreSQL version, as 8.4 is out of support for many years now.  Also, depending on the RAM you have, think about raising `shared_buffers` to something bigger (unless you have a very small DB).  Finally, `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` shows information about cached data.

Comment: But why would the plan change? There was no change in the data, the query, or the schema. Also, 8.4 is the version supported by the client, and there's no real change we can do for that, which also means I can't run the `explain buffers` command.

Comment: It's hard to guess, but for example autoanalyze might run only some time after a change in the data.  That means the plan flip can happen also later, in no apparent connection with the data change itself.